# Can I safely use Task.Wait when SynchronizationContext.Current is null?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, deadlock

Why is it not 100% safe to call Task.Wait() and Task.Result when SynchronizationContext.Current is null?

I have a multi-threaded but synchronous service.  I am replacing one of the synchronous methods with a call to HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync.  The implementation uses .Result to convert that into a synchronous method, to avoid changing the entire project.  However, we are getting the typical deadlock problems that are well documented.

I don't understand how there could be a deadlock if there is no synchronization context.

Comment: Maybe you can post at least some code. By service you mean windows service?

Comment: @Evk - he probably means a webservice

Comment: Why are you using asynchronous  methods in the first place, if you're just going to wait for them to finish?  Just use the inherently synchronous methods from the start if you want to perform synchronous operations.  There's no *purpose* to making a few methods asynchronous if you're just going to wait on them anyway.  Either that, or just make the service handler asynchronous.

Comment: Can you clarify what context you're actually in, given that you don't have a `SynchronizationContext`?  Is it a custom Windows Service?  Console app?

Comment: @Evk This is a Windows service.  Actually, we are running it as a console app for now since it is just easier.

Comment: @Servy I actually don't want to use an async method at all.  HttpClient just seemed like the natural way to call an Xml service.  I could use HttpWebRequest, and write code to serialize/deserialize the Xml.  That's our alternative.  But really, I just want to understand *why* it is a problem in this case.  Is there a better class to use rather than HttpClient or HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Well it should not deadlock in console application, so some code (or even minimal reproduceable example) won't hurt.

Comment: @Evk okay, so my understanding is correct then?  Hmmm, I'll try to recreate it in a smaller demo app.  Perhaps I should mention that one of the classes we are using hosts an OWIN service?  No IIS involved though.  And that isn't the thread we are on when making the HttpClient call.

Comment: Yes sure that is important, because since it serves requests it has the same (conceptually) synchronization context as asp.net application - after async call is completed it should return to the context of current request. So your unserstanding is correct, but your assumption that context is null might be not.

Comment: @Evk I put in some debugging code to check that the context is null.

Comment: Haven't you answered the question posed in your title yourself? You thought that you could, but you're now encountering deadlock-like behaviour. And so the answer is "obviously not". If you want a concrete explanation for why it's not working in your scenario, please try to construct an MCVE so that we can reason about your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no synchronization context, the [typical problems with blocking](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) on async code will not happen.  However, it is not 100% safe: if the thread belongs to the thread pool, blocking will keep the thread from returning to the pool, which can cause you to run out of thread pool threads.

In my case, the problem was actually caused by our corporate proxy server.  Given enough time, the threads would indeed come back.  I changed my code to pass the HttpClient an HttpClientHandler with UseProxy=false, and the problems went away.

Answer (score -1):

Method `HttpClient.PostAsXmlAsync` is extension method which execute `HttpClient.SendAsync` in background. `SendAsync` method is asynchronous method.
So you calling asynchronous method in "synchronous" way - which lead to the very well documented deadlock as you noticed by yourself.

> ... to convert that into a synchronous method, to avoid changing the
>   entire project

To avoid changing whole application pipeline to `async` - do not use `async`.
`async-await` is a zombie virus which spread all over your application when you start used it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "method which create synchronization context."  I believe calling await *captures* the context.  I am not aware of SendAsync or await *creating* a synchronization context.